# Edit mp3 id3 lyrics data c#

Tags: c#, mp3, id3

I've seen many solutions for editing Artist and Album info, etc, but is there a way to edit the lyrics in mp3 id3 data? There are softwares for this, but I'm asking if there's a way to program this in c#. Let's say I have the lyrics in text files for all of my music files, how do I put them into the mp3 files?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no internal built-in solution for this, you will have to use an external library such as these:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/csid3lib/

http://id3.codeplex.com/

The latter looks more complete and feature rich.

For example, to get the lyrics of a file:

```
string[] mp3Files = Directory.GetFiles(_mp3Directory, "*.mp3");

            InfoProvider chartLyricsProvider = new ChartLyricsInfoProvider();
            InfoProvider lyrDbLyricsProvider = new LyrDbInfoProvider();
            foreach (string mp3File in mp3Files)
            {
                Console.Write(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(mp3File));

                Id3Tag tag;
                using (var mp3 = new Mp3File(mp3File))
                    tag = mp3.GetTag(Id3TagFamily.FileStartTag);
                if (tag == null)
                    continue;

                if (!tag.Artists.IsAssigned || !tag.Title.IsAssigned)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    continue;
                }

                Console.WriteLine(" ({0} - {1})", tag.Artists.Values[0], tag.Title.Value);

                Id3Tag[] lyricsTags = GetLyrics(tag, chartLyricsProvider, lyrDbLyricsProvider);
                if (lyricsTags == null || lyricsTags.Length == 0)
                    continue;

                string outputFilename = string.Format("{0} - {1}.txt", tag.Artists.Values[0], tag.Title.Value);
                string outputFile = Path.Combine(_outputDirectory, outputFilename);
                using (var lyricsWriter = new StreamWriter(outputFile, false))
                    lyricsWriter.Write(lyricsTags[0].Lyrics[0].Lyrics);

                Console.WriteLine("    {0}", outputFilename);
            }
```

I am sure that after looking through the docs of both those libraries, you can find how to assign lyrics.

Comment: Okay I kind of understood what the first does. Now if I have the lyrics in text I think i can save it to the mp3 file. But what I don't understand is how to get the lyrics from that ChartLyrics thing. For me it does not recognise InfoProvider and many other things.

Comment: But thanks very much so far at least now I can start off with something.

Comment: How can I do that?

(Sorry I am not used to using external library's.)

Comment: First, add a reference to the dll, then at the top of our file `using Id3.Info;
using Id3.Info.ChartLyrics;
using Id3.Info.LyrDb;`

Comment: I added the dll's from http://id3.codeplex.com/ and now it accepts using Id3.Info but not the ChartLyrics and the LyrDb. What should I do now?

Comment: @weiszam Can we [continue this in chat?](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7/c)

Answer (score 0):

Some quick googling revealed this. Perhaps it may work for you?

http://sourceforge.net/projects/id3dotnet/

Comment: I'm kind of confused with this, I don't know how to import dll's and such things, but with the other source I can modify the lyrics now, so the only thing left is to download the lyrics easily. If you know an easy way.. :)